# Using JSF resource in EL

Tags: jsf-2, el

I've the following style in a css file:

```
.sectionDivider {
    background-image: url('#{resource['default:../img/dashes.png']}'); 
    background-position:center; width:100%; 
    background-repeat: repeat-x; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; 
}
```

When running my app, I'm getting this EL expression error:
Cannot evaluate EL expression resource['default:../img/dashes.png'] in resource default:css/it.css

Can't spot what I did that is wrong.

Comment: Those periods really doesn't belong there. The resource name is always relative to the resource library.

Comment: @BalusC:  I added the .. thinking that I need that because path ini CSS is relative to the CSS file.  After I made the change as you suggested, I see what it is doing now.  Thanks.  That solved the problem.